# x=x+1 syntax error inside a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, increment

I am trying to increment a variable(count) inside a for loop if a condition is satisfied. But, I am getting a syntax error at the increment statement. Please help.

```
def count_ans():
    count=0
    for m in range(0,4):
        if quiz_dict[q_nos[m]==ans_list[m]:
            count += 1    #<--syntax error
return count
```

Comment: Count the number of square brackets on the line before where the error is

Comment: return is outside of the function, missing a closing bracket, quiz_dict is not defined, q_nos is not defined, ans_list is not defined....

Answer (score 0):

Follwong should be the function

def count_ans():

```
count=0
for m in range(0,4):
    if quiz_dict[q_nos[m]]==ans_list[m]:  ##### Square bracket was missing
        count += 1   
return count                        #### Return was outside the function
```